# Simulate mobile operator in PHP

Tags: php

I need to access some websites as a mobile device (Header simulation) and additionally have to simulate access through a mobile carrier / operator.

The reason is that pages are delivering different content when accessing through a smartphone with WiFi/W-LAN or cell network (mobile operator).

Is there any way to approach this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The page maybe delivering content basing on your User Agent.

You can open the page in Chrome, press F12 key on your keyboard and then click on a small "mobile" icon (2nd one from the left).

This will simulate a mobile device. You can select the user agent or the device from the drop down menu from the preferences.

Comment: The page is somehow differentiating between Wifi and Cell access. No change of the Header.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to approach to this situation is using a "SIM simulator", some enterprises that have Direct Operator Billing have this systems that test the operator using a real SIM with his servers using a Proxy browser system.

The header it's not part of that simulation, normally the operator uses the "ip & the identification of SIM" to do that identification, when is thru WIFI needs de number to check with the operator service.